# Can a topology induced from closed balls?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, d)$ be a pseudometric space. If one define closed balls 
$B_r(x):=\{y\in X\mid d(x, y) \leq r\}$ with $r>0$, can the topology defined by the pseudometric distance $d$ be obtained from the closed balls?

Comment: One could consider the topology generated by the complements of the closed balls, in other words take the complements of the closed balls as a sub-bases for a topology. But in $\mathbb{R}$, for example, that's not the same as the ordinary topology.

Comment: When you say "get the topology of $X$" do you mean this in the sense of "can we figure out the topology of $X$ given just the set of closed balls" or do you mean to ask if the set of closed balls generates the topology or something else?

Comment: Yes, I should the topology induced from the pseudometric distance $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\mathbb{R}$ as an example, if $\beta(x_0;r)$ is an open ball centred at $x_0$ with radius $r$,
$$ \bigcup_{x \in \beta(x_0;r)} B_0(x) = \beta(x_0;r)
$$
so unions of closed balls may become open balls. It implies that the closed-ball topology is finer than the Euclidean topology. In fact, singletons are both open (being a closed ball of radius 0) and closed.(since the topology is finer) Therefore closed balls generate the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

In general we could define Topology by closed sets. Let $X$ be any set and let $\tau$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. We say $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ if and only:

1. Any intersection of arbitrarily many closed sets of $X$ under $\tau$ is a closed set of $X$ under $\tau$.
2. The union of any finite number of closed sets of $X$ under $\tau$ is a closed set of $X$ under $\tau$.
3. $X$ and $\emptyset$ are both closed sets of $X$ under $\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: not always.

If you consider a space $\mathbb{R}$ with it's typical metric (**metric is also pseudometric**),then closed balls will not give topology. Intersection of two closed balls can give a point as a result. Point can't be expressed as a sum of closed balls created with using euclidean distance as the metric. But you can also consider discrete metric ($1_{\mathbb{R}-x_0}$). In that case point can be a closed ball.Such a topology includes all the subsets and meets conditions of being topology.